# After invalidate the session in jsf still it is giving session values

Tags: jsf, session

while logout i did removed session object and invalidated session also as like below

```
public String logout() throws IOException {
        logger.info("logout() : satarted----- ");
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.getSessionMap().remove("visitorComponent");
        System.out.println("*************_->"+ec.getSessionMap().remove("visitorComponent"));
        ec.invalidateSession();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/logout.xhtml");
        return null;
//      return "logout?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

But still in filter class its giving values, filter class code like below

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        if (session.getAttribute("visitorComponent") != null) {
            System.out.println("-sdf>"+((VisitorComponent) session.getAttribute("visitorComponent")).getAdmin());
        }
        System.out.println("->"+session.getAttribute("visitorComponent"));
        System.out.println("=url>"+req.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println("=>"+req.getRequestURI().endsWith("login.xhtml"));
        if (session.getAttribute("visitorComponent") != null || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("index.xhtml")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, httpResponse);
        } else {
            System.out.println("---in else--");
//            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect("index.xhtml");
            return;
        }

    }
```

Could you please help any one, what I need to do?

Comment: Are you sure about the `logout()` method which is properly invoked, when you initiate the logout process? Which resources (URL pattern) this `Filter` is mapped to?

Comment: I seen with debug Yes sure, logout invoking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I caught solution. 
Why because it is not loading all primefaces UI effects is, 
For every request our filter is checking so in Filter class we have to write condition to allow our CSS and JS file as like below

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        if (session.getAttribute("loginDetails") != null
                || session.getAttribute("empLoginDetails") != null
                || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("index.xhtml")
                || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("forgetpass.xhtml")
                || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("empLogin.xhtml")
                || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("logout.xhtml")
                || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("ajax-loader.gif.xhtml")
                || req.getRequestURI().contains(".js")
                || req.getRequestURI().contains(".css")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            if (fc == null) {
                // Create new Lifecycle.
                LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder
                        .getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
                Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory
                        .getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);

                // Create new FacesContext.
                FacesContextFactory contextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder
                        .getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
                fc = contextFactory.getFacesContext(
                        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession()
                                .getServletContext(), request, response,
                        lifecycle);
            }

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/index.xhtml");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            return;
        }
```

Now my application is working fine with filter class

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution but side effects are there.

My solution is, previously I was not kept login object manually because my login class in session scope. If i do in this way its not clear the object after invalidate also because while starting application login class instantiated.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "visitorComponent")
@SessionScoped
public class VisitorComponent {

  Admin admin = new Admin();

 public String login() {
     // some code to verify login details
     this.admin = adminService.getAdminObject(adminId);
 }
```

Now i did manually by get session object map and put my login object in session map.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "visitorComponent")
@SessionScoped
public class VisitorComponent {

  Admin admin = new Admin();

 public String login() {
     // some code to verify login details
     this.admin = adminService.getAdminObject(adminId);
     // Session object creating to get the session values
                    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                            .getExternalContext();
                    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
                    sessionMap.put("abcadminBean", this.admin);
 }
```

Now its working fine by invalidate but problem is in my login page 
i have

I have doubt in my filterclass, that is like below

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        if (session.getAttribute("abcadminBean") != null || req.getRequestURI().endsWith("index.xhtml")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            if (fc == null) {
                // Create new Lifecycle.
                LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory)
                    FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY); 
                Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);

                // Create new FacesContext.
                FacesContextFactory contextFactory  = (FacesContextFactory)
                    FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
                fc = contextFactory.getFacesContext(
                    ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);
            }
            System.out.println("fc->"+fc);
            ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
            ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");
//            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
//          ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("index.xhtml");
            return;
        }

    }
```

Here I am redirecting my page, I thought it is the problem
Could you please any one help me, What i need to do for my UI changes ?

Comment: Mainly Primfaces components not loading in first page(index.xhtml) only. That is only problem, even that is comming with redirection.

Comment: Do you really need to deal with all of those factories in the `Filter`'s `doFilter()` method?

Comment: Yes I need use Filter